# C# - if statements against parts of a string

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I basically want to check if part of a string begins with a certain sequence - in this case ftp://, or http://. How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Too easy...prepare for the deluge!

Comment: Re-reading this question I wonder if by " *part of a string* begins with a certain sequence" he means that the string must contain some substring that starts with ftp://?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [**`String.StartsWith`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx). With just two possible prefixes you can write it as follows:

```
if (s.StartsWith("http://") || s.StartsWith("ftp://")) { ... }
```

If you have a lot of different possible prefixes it might be better to use a loop or a LINQ expression instead. For example:

```
string[] prefixes = { "http://", "ftp://", /* etc... */ };
if (prefixes.Any(prefix => s.StartsWith(prefix)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: seconded... Appreciate the use of LINQ here

Answer (score 4):

```
  if(myString.StartsWith("ftp://") || myString.StartsWith("http://")) { }
```

if you wish it to ignore case then use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

```
  if(myString.StartsWith("ftp://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || myString.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { }
```

Comment: If wish it to ignore case, it would be better to use: 
myString.StartsWith("ftp://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: @Dylan - quite right in this scenario, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( myString.StartsWith("ftp://")){
  ...
}
```

Similar if you want to check for http://, but change the parameter to StartsWith.

Answer (score 1):

[String.StartsWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd suggest use Regex, but the most basic form is

```
string myText = @"http://blabla.com";
if (myText.IndexOf("http://") == 0 || myText.IndexOf("ftp://") == 0))
{
//dosome
}
```

Comment: @Øyvind, in this case it probably would, but in a more general case it could well be more performant, depending on the complexity of the test required.

Comment: true; performance will drop, but ussually you start with.. I want to know of http is a part of the string.. and you end with: I need to know if the url is valid

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) method.